# Finding methods of classes from the use case

Tags: class-diagram, use-case

I know some nouns in the use case scenario are candidate to be class, for example `member`, `customer`, `student` ....

I can find such entities and some attributes of them, but my problem is that I can't easily find any method for these classes.

Which part of use cases are candidate for methods or functions of classes?

Please give some examples.
For example in a system for hospital, `Patient` or `Doctor` are classes, what are the functions for these classes?

Comment: Draw sequence diagrams for the use-cases. This will give you domain classes, which you can then use your design skills to define real classes.

Comment: Please read : http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/CoffeeMaker.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If the nouns are the classes the verbs are the functions. In your use case the nouns presumably do things? These are the candidates for functions of the classes.

Comment: could you please give some examples?

Comment: @Ahmad -- Student enrolls, attends .... . Customer orders, pays, receives returns ..... Member joins, subscribes, votes